# How to run java jar file in robot framework

Tags: python, jar, robotframework

I have converted java program to jar file. I want to run the jar file in robot framework. How can I import and run in background? and also i want to stop the running jar file after sometime(max 15mins)

Comment: What have you tried and what did you observe?

Comment: I run py script in terminal and it will trigger the jar. The Jar will not return any output instead it will run as an OS Process in Background and populate data in a text file.  
import subprocess 
subprocess.check_output(['java', '-jar', 'test.jar'])
I want to run the above script using robot framework. The script should run at background and end at certain time(15mins). 
If I create library function and call in RF, it is throwing error
Importing test library 'stg.py' failed: CalledProcessError: Command '['java', '-jar', 'test.jar']' returned non-zero exit status 130.

Comment: Can you add your comment to your question using the [edit] functionality. That way all the information is in one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Process` library. It has several keywords that can help you. For example, in your case, you case use `Wait For Process` and specify what you want to do after a timeout is reached.

You can take a look to the [library documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Start%20Process). You can do something like:

```
Start Process    java    -jar    ${jars}${/}example.jar
${result}=    Wait For Process    timeout=1min 30s    on_timeout=kill
```